# having trouble deploying backend to azure

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure

So I have a web app that has an Angular frontend and a Node.js backend. I'm trying to deploy to Azure using the Azure App Extension in Visual Studio Code. However, this is my first time using Azure so I don't really know what I should do. Right now I have two web apps, one for the frontend and one for the backend, and they are using the same App Service Plan and Resource Group.

When I try deploying the backend, it won't even deploy it. I've tried changing the folder its being deployed from, using the KUDU console to zip deploy, but nothing works.

I tried a tutorial to make a test project and upload that to Azure (as shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01?tabs=bash). That test project deployed perfectly fine to Azure, however, when I went back to try my source code, the folders wouldn't deploy. How do i fix this problem?

**Edit**: After doing some troubleshooting, I'm getting these error messages:

- Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file D:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\oplaw3rp.zip (178.92 MB) to D:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted
- There is not enough space on the disk.\r\n

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running out of disk space before the zip fully extracts. Upgrade to Basic or Standard SKU (10 GB of storage) see if that fixes it.

App Service Plans compared -
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Comment: I've heard there is also a "Local Cache" setting in Azure. Is that a viable option?

Comment: Yes but that's a cache, so you still need storage to populate the cache.